# how can we change the state value in a depends method?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, depends

how can we change the **state** value in a **@api.depends** method ?
I tried the  `return {'value':{'stat':'done'}}` and `self.state='done'`
didn't work
then `self.browse(self.id).write({'state':'done' })`  worked but on instant, we have to *return to the list* view or to *reload* the page to see the **new state**

Comment: In v11 when you write state then you have to manually refresh page to see new state. By default it will not refreshed.

Comment: @KevalMehta but the `return` doesn't work

Comment: `return` is working in api.depends

Answer (score 0):

your problem can be resolved using this.

```
@api.onchange('your_field')
def your_method_name(self):
    self.state='done'
    return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.client',
            'tag': 'reload',
            }
```

Comment: try to use onchange

Comment: I cannot use the onchange because the function must listening to a related a the One2many  field

Comment: suppose you are in sale order and you want to apply onchange on product_id from sale order @api.onchange('order_line.product_id')

Comment: `onchange` didn't change the situation, same as `depends`